# Where can I find WSDLs in Websphere web console interface

Tags: configuration, wsdl, websphere

Yep, that's the question.

I didn't manage to find web service endpoints in websphere console. But I'm pretty sure they must be there, please help.

Answer (score 3):

For JAX-WS services you can find it in two places:

- Applications > WebSphere enterprise applications > *applicationName* > Publish WSDL files
- or Services > Service providers > *serviceName* > View WSDL

And you can access it via service url also: `http://host:port/context/serviceName?wsdl`

Comment: What version of WebSphere are you using? I'm on 8.5 and there is no Publish WSDL files option

Comment: @DanK I'm using 8.5.5, but that option is since quite a time. You are probably using third party WebService engine, bundled with application, instead the one provided in the container. In that case there is no integration with the console, and you will have to access wsdl via url.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find or set the web service endpoint in administration console(for WAS version 6.1) go to:
Applications>Enterprise Applications>App Name>**Provide HTTP endpoint URL information**

Answer (score 0):

Go to Enterprise Applications >  -> Service providers(under Web Service Properties) >, you will see the wsdl file.
even it can be found Enterprise Applications >  > Publish WSDL files(its under Web Service Properties)